# Objective C: Incrementing/Decrementing an integer, starting at 20

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm new to xcode and objective C.

My goal is to create an app to keep score for magic the gathering games.

Starting with an integer of 0 is easy. However, in Magic the Gathering, each player begins with 20 lives, and either gains or loses lives from there.

The implementation below increases and decreases the label by 1. Great! However, it overrides my label value set at 20 (on the storyboard) and starts again at 0.

Unfortunately, at this stage I don't understand enough how integer storage works in objective-c to troubleshoot (my experience in ruby is obviously no help here).

Here's my ViewController.h file:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Counter
//
//  Created by Gregory Hill on 1/24/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 mrsenorhill. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property int counter;
- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)decrement:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here's my ViewController.m:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Counter
//
//  Created by Gregory Hill on 1/24/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 mrsenorhill. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)decrement:(id)sender {
    self.counter -= 1;
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.counter]];
}

- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender {
    self.counter += 1;
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.counter]];
}


@end
```

I've searched all over SO, but I don't know enough to find what I'm looking for. I assume I need to set my label in the implementation to 20, (in the ViewController.m), but I don't have the slightest idea how to do so.

Comment: You need to set both self.counter and your label to 20 initially.

Comment: Do I do that in the header as a propery? Or in an IBAction for both actions in the .m?

Comment: Neither. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both self.counter and your label to 20 initially because otherwise self.counter equals 0 by default. For example, in `viewDidLoad` you can set both the label text and counter like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.label setText:@"20"];
    self.counter = 20;
}
```

You can also set your label's initial text to "20" in the interface.

Comment: Bees knees. Thank you for the quick response Lyndsey!